# Go: Why is "mapping between XML and data structures flawed"?

Tags: xml, go

In the Go XML package, [there is a comment](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#pkg-note-BUG):

> Mapping between XML elements and data structures is inherently flawed: an XML element is an order-dependent collection of anonymous values, while a data structure is an order-independent collection of named values. See package json for a textual representation more suitable to data structures.

Why would someone assert this? A data structure can also be, for example, an array, which is an order-dependent collection of values.

XML may typically be verbose and complex but I can't see the argument that mapping it to a data structure is flawed. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Sure you could use a slice, but what do you do when you add an attribute, or another element type, or inner text? There's also no canonical way to marshal a data structure to an element. What comprises an attribute vs a sub-element, or a namespace? A map isn't ordered, and can produce different XML each time it's marshaled. There are a lot of reasons there's no 1 to 1 mapping.

Comment: I don't understand why that would preclude translation between the two. Why not just add another struct member for an attribute, create a new type for an element, or have a struct member for inner text? A map isn't ordered, but you don't need to use a map, you can just use an array.

Comment: Of course you can represent an XML document with a combination of purpose designed data structures. What you can't do is use it as a generalized serialization format for a struct and map that directly to an XML element.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand the original comment now thanks to your explanation. You should put your texts as an answer!